# SAML Based SSO between Angular App and Another Java/Servlet/JSP App

Tags: angular, websphere, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have a scenario where User Login and Credentials are maintained in a Client-side IDP. And as a Service provider, we have 2 Web Applications.

1. App-1: Developed in Angular 9
2. App-2: It's a COTS Product where the Web Application is a Servlet JSP App running on WebSphere Application Server.

Now, the Second App does not support SP-initiated authentication. Hence the flow we are thinking is:

- Step-1: User access the Angular App
- Step-2: Angular App has all the users stored and maintained in the system (except login credentials)
- Step-3: Angular App routes the user to User IdP (Azure AD) to get Authenticated over OIDC and a Token is returned to Angular App with user id and role details.
- Step-4: Angular App retrieves all the user properties from application DB.
- Step-5: Now Angular App will create a SAML request and will send it to App-2.

**Is the above flow possible and can some share ant link of documentation around how to set up the SAML generation from Angular for the App-2 SSO.**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IdP initiated flow Step-5 is where App-1 switches from being an SP to an IdP. App-1 creates a SAML Response containing authentication information and attributes for the user. Attributes specific to Azure should not be sent to App-2 as it has no relationship with that IdP. It only has a relationship with App-1 as an IdP.

An example SAML Response is [here](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php). App-2 will need to have App-1's SAML metadata in order to validate signatures etc. You can build IdP SAML metadata [here](https://www.samltool.com/idp_metadata.php).

However, note [the dangers of IdP initiated SSO](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/the-dangers-of-saml-idp-initiated-sso).